# How to connect with Delphi to redis-sentinel

Tags: delphi, redis, redis-sentinel

I want to build a high available Redis datastore which I'd configure with the Redis-Sentinel. In order to Connect to this Sentinel with a [Delphi Redis Client](https://github.com/danieleteti/delphiredisclient), how will it be done?

As the [Documentation](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel#sentinel-clients-implementation) of Redis tells, it is required that the used Redis Client supports Redis-Sentinel. I didn't fine that Sentinel is supported in that mentioded Redis Client for Delphi.

Could please tell me some hone how to Connect to Redis-Sentinel with or without functionality of given Client?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Did you see this: https://github.com/danieleteti/delphiredisclient ?

Comment: yes, but i don't see any sentinel function nor procedure in that Client.

Comment: I once tried to make a really really raw 'redis connector' here: https://github.com/stijnsanders/TRedisWire